# What information can a browser track about me on the internet?

Tags: ip, www

When I go a to a website, what sort of information can that server collect about my identity, under normal circumstances? I knows they can track my IP address and operating system. What else is there?

Comment: try this: http://browserspy.dk/

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is far too broad for Super User. There are many, many ways websites can track you, and they depend on your browser, privacy settings, installed plugins, etc.

Comment: @Dennis: Isn't this probably a dupe of [How much information can websites get about your browser/PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/470348/how-much-information-can-websites-get-about-your-browser-pc) If so, given the previous QotW and related SU blog post, Erik your question would quite likely have been closed anyway.

Comment: @Erik: Instead of leaving comments like that, it would nice if you would take the time to improve your question so that it becomes acceptable for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, here is an idea of the things tracked by Google Analytics (the free one).  This is a very non-exhaustive list and only scrape the surface:

- Operating System (and version)
- IP Address
- Location (Easily down to the City, but really it could probably get down to a house if necessary).
- Language
- Browser type
- Screen Resolution
- ISP

There are various other things, depending on plugins, cookies, and so-forth.  But that gets you a basic start.