# Why does a specific website force the mobile interface on Desktop browser when using tethering?

Tags: firefox, website, mobile-ui

#### How is [MakeMyTrip](http://www.makemytrip.com/) able to detect that I'm using tethering or internet(using [SIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_identity_module) card) and therefore, serving me its mobile interface against my will? How do I get rid of this issue without giving up the tethering?

The website in the title is [MakeMyTrip](http://www.makemytrip.com/). One month ago, I booked my ticket for a journey through this website. I used my Firefox 36.0 (Linux) to do such. The user-agent wasn't tweaked either. The website provided me with its Desktop based interface and all went well.

Today, I opened the website and was greeted with its mobile interface. I double-checked my user-agent and found it unchanged. Inside History, I did `Forgot this website` to delete any trace of this website. I then restarted my browser but still got the same interface. I created new Firefox profile too but to no avail. The issue can be reproduced in Chromium 41.0. Browsers in my other Desktop system are giving the same results.

It has to be mentioned that I use my Android (4.x.x) device for tethering and browsing the internet. I tried via tethering, two different devices ([1](http://www.airtel.in/),[2](http://www.bsnl.co.in/opencms/bsnl/BSNL/services/mobile/tariff_excel_pre.html)) with different telecommunication providers and found the same result. In the devices itself, under [Firefox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&hl=en) app, opening this website with default user-agent gives a page with link to Play Store for its [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.makemytrip&hl=en). Using `Request Desktop Site` falls back to the same aforementioned mobile interface of the website.

Other fact to be noted is that the website doesn't behave in this fashion when you're accessing it from non-SIM enabled internet connectivity. The website opens its default Desktop interface if it is opened through TOR, any open proxy server, college proxy, etc. The website also shows default Desktop interface for my mobile broadband [Tata Photon Plus](http://www.tataphoton.com/photon-plus.aspx) device too.

**Note**: A slightly similar question was asked on SuperUser [here](https://superuser.com/questions/693829/how-do-web-sites-detect-mobile-devices), but was closed for being Off-Topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website is using Geo-tags on the IP addresses to choose which site layout to provide. It's on their end. You may be out of luck unless you contact their support.

Comment: May I know how did you confirm this?

Comment: It's common practice. IANA provides blocks of IPs to RIRs. RIRs give blocks of IPs to local ISPs. ISPs divide the blocks up among clients. The website is asks who the block is assigned to. It's told that the block belongs to *INSERT-ISP-HERE* and makes a choice based on that. Say I did the same thing with my phone, the website would see that it's getting a request from a Verizon Wireless subscriber and send me the appropriate page.